# How do I make tomcat include libs from the current project?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, classpath, libs

I've read somewhere as a good practice, that it's better to have the required libs included in each project, then just add all the libs you'll ever need to the tomcat folder. Well right now Tomcat seems to need all the required libs to be in lib folder of Tomcat. How can I make it use the libs from the build path of the project? i'm using tomcat 7.032 in through Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libraries of a webapp must be in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the deployed web application directory or war file.

Every jar file in this directory will be in the classpath of the webapp, and won't be in the classpath of the other deployed webapps. You indeed shouldn't put webapp libraries into Tomcat's classpath.